# How can I force pairs of brackets [][] to be closer to each other in \texttt?

Tags: fonts, spacing, brackets, typewriter

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}
Normal margin here. Normal margin here. Normal margin here.
Normal margin here. Normal margin here. Normal margin here. Normal margin here.

Abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcd: \texttt{float[][]} and
\texttt{double[][]}.
\end{document}
```

As you can see `[]` is far from other `[]`. How can I get them closer to each other?
What is more, `double[][]` extends beyond the margin line. How could this be written better?

I'm using minted package. Is it possible to write small code samples inline using it?

[image]

Comment: It's an artifact of monospaced font. Compare the following `\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}
% 
\verb+double||||+
%
\verb+double[][]+.
\end{document}
`.(Introduce new lines at the comments such that they align vertically to see the location of each character)

Comment: as @percusse says the distinguishing feature of a monospace font is that all the characters are the same width, so `W` and `.` are the same width. If you do not want that, rather than adding spacing between `[]` perhaps you would prefer a different font, say `\textsf{float[][]}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it doesn't occur very often or you can use search and replace you can add a negative space by yourself to compensate for it:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}
Normal margin here. Normal margin here. Normal margin here.
Normal margin here. Normal margin here. Normal margin here. Normal margin here.

Abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcd: \texttt{float[]$\!$[]} and
\texttt{double[]\kern-.2em[]}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

In theory it should also be possible to change the kerning of `]` and `[`, but I can't tell you if this can be done with some reasonable amount of work. Maybe the `microtype` package can help?

Comment: if the kerning of the brackets were changed, it would no longer be a monospace font.

Comment: Changing the kerning between two characters is not easy in LaTeX. `microtype` can change a  character's kerning, but that will influence the kerning between that character and all other characters. Your solution is simple and it works, i.e. most likely the best.